# can not delete file using BOX SDK on android

Tags: android, box-api, box, boxapiv2

I'm fresh with box sdk, I'm trying to use it to delete my box file,but it seems doesn't work. Here is my code, authentication works fine but delete function has problem:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Button button_login;
private Button button_logout;
private Button button_delete;

BoxSession session=null;
BoxApiFile file_delete_api = null;
BoxFile file_delete = null;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_login);
    button_logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_logout);
    button_delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_delete);


    BoxConfig.CLIENT_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    BoxConfig.CLIENT_SECRET = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    BoxConfig.REDIRECT_URL = "http://0.0.0.0";

    session = new BoxSession(MainActivity.this);


    button_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           // BoxApiFile fileApi = new BoxApiFile(session);
            session.authenticate();


        }
    });

    button_logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            session.logout();
        }
    });

    button_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new deletefile().execute();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public class deletefile extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        file_delete_api = new BoxApiFile(session);
        try {
            file_delete = file_delete_api.getInfoRequest("f_33651677581").send();
           // file_delete = file_delete_api.getUpdateRequest("f_33651677581").setName("change").setDescription("test change").send();
        } catch (BoxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Here is the exception from log:

```
07-22 21:12:08.582  26066-26287/? W/System.err﹕ at com.box.androidsdk.content.requests.BoxRequest.send(BoxRequest.java:177)
07-22 21:12:08.582  26066-26287/? W/System.err﹕ at com.example.kuhou.box_test_delete_file.MainActivity$deletefile.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:102)
07-22 21:12:08.582  26066-26287/? W/System.err﹕ at com.example.kuhou.box_test_delete_file.MainActivity$deletefile.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:95)
07-22 21:12:08.582  26066-26287/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-22 21:12:08.582  26066-26287/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-22 21:12:08.582  26066-26287/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-22 21:12:08.582  26066-26287/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-22 21:12:08.582  26066-26287/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
07-22 21:12:08.582  26066-26287/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-22 21:12:08.582  26066-26287/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
```

It seems like there is some thing wrong with

```
 file_delete = file_delete_api.getInfoRequest("f_33651677581").send();
```

Is there anyone can help? Thanks a lots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the leading `f_` from the file ID. That prefix appears in the web UI but the ID is just the numeric portion.

```
file_delete = file_delete_api.getInfoRequest("33651677581").send();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, as what you were talking about, I remove this "f_", the exception gone, but it doesn't delete this file. My file URL is https://app.box.com/files/0/f/0/1/f_33651677581,is there anything wrong with my code? Thank you @John Hoerr

Comment: Can you do anything else to the file, like change its name or description?

Comment: no, I only can do authentication. login and logout. Is there anything I miss? I use file_delete = file_delete_api.getInfoRequest("33651677581").send(); into the sample of box it doesn't work as well. Thank you

Comment: I'd recommend that you try to reproduce the issue with the [Box Android SDK sample application](https://github.com/box/box-android-sdk).

Comment: Thank you that really help me a lots. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the request type you're using to a delete request:

```
    BoxApiFile fileApi = new BoxApiFile(session);
    try {
        fileApi.getDeleteRequest("33651677581").send();
    } catch (BoxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was misused the api. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, wow, yeah -- this is obviously correct. Good eye, letstango.